# How to use max with having in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table called user which is provided below as image. In the given table I want to select the largest value whose offset is 1.

[image: Table]

The query which I have used is below:

```
select offset, max(value) as max_val from user having offset = 1
```

from the above query I was expecting `max_value = 4` but I am getting `max_value = 0`. Please help me.

Comment: invalid query as you can't mix a non aggregat column with a aggregate column without using group by

Comment: I posted answer please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `WHERE` clause with `GROUP BY` is sufficient in your scenario:

```
SELECT `offset`, max(value) as max_val 
FROM `user` 
WHERE `offset` = 1
GROUP by `offset`
```

Also try to avoid the [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-O) as the column names, you may need to escape the column name by encasing in **`** (backtick)

or using having with `GROUP BY`

```
select `offset`, max(value) as max_val 
from `user` 
group by `offset`
having `offset` = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a little trick here to avoid to need to use `GROUP BY`

This query (Arulkumar 's answer)

**Query**

```
SELECT `offset`, max(value) as max_val 
FROM `user` 
WHERE `offset` = 1
GROUP by `offset`
```

Can be rewritten to the query below. 
**Note** only possible when you filter on one condition like `offset = 1` two or more conditions like `offset IN(1, 2)` can't be converted

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   '1' AS `offset`
  , MAX(CASE WHEN `offset` = 1 THEN `value` END) AS max_val
FROM 
 a
```

**Results**

```
| offset | max_val |
| ------ | ------- |
| 1      | 4       |
```

**Note**
That this is valid SQL as `'1' AS offset` is a literal and does not need to be grouped. 
So it's valid with ANSI/ISO SQL standards regarding the `GROUP BY` and with MySQL's `sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` which enforces you to write valid `GROUP BY` SQL

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aYHentqq8fD653Uopizv9h/0)

**More optimized version**

```
SELECT 
 '1' AS `offset`
, MAX(`value`) AS max_val
FROM 
 a 
WHERE 
 a.`offset` = 1
```

As it can use indexes instead of table scanning see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aYHentqq8fD653Uopizv9h/0)

**Bonus**

You can also use a self joined left join on the same table to simulate MAX/MIN aggregate functions to also avoid `GROUP BY`. 
Plus you can use this on more two or more conditions like `offset IN(1, 2)`

**Simulates max**

```
  SELECT 
     *
    FROM 
     a a1 
    LEFT JOIN
     a a2 
    ON
       a1.offset = a2.offset
     AND
       a1.value < a2.value
    WHERE
     a2.value IS NULL
```

**Results**

```
| offset | value | offset | value |
| ------ | ----- | ------ | ----- |
| 1      | 4     |        |       |
| 2      | 4     |        |       |
| 3      | 4     |        |       |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aYHentqq8fD653Uopizv9h/1) with filter `WHERE offset = 1` see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aYHentqq8fD653Uopizv9h/2)

Answer (score -1):

Check this is query

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE `offset` = 1 ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What does this query do? How does it work?  *Why* does it work? Please explain and expand your answer. Thank you `:-)`

Comment: This is the efficient query but under the condition that I have value only in increasing order!!

Comment: @utsavprasad but you can use for select data this query will not update table.

Comment: @Martin Author has found this query efficient this will give you answer of all your questions.

Comment: @RonakChauhan considering certain manipulation in the table I am not sure that i will have the value in increasing order and also there are certain edge case under which the query will fail. It is well trick but brings some limitations.

Comment: If you need only one record from table this will 100% work fine. But I think you have asked question very poorly and did not mentioned what exactly you need.